# iPad Voice Recognition - Developer Access?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

So, the iPad 3 just came out so this may be too early to ask this question. However, they announced at the event that there would be voice recognition built in to iPad 3. Will developers have access to this? Also, any idea if any time information for when words were said would be accessible as well? And if you cannot get time information on when words were said, could you have a separate process running in the background that is just a timer which could be matched up with the dictated text?

I looked in the iOS class reference and this was the closest thing I found, but not sure if this could possibly be it?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDictationPhraseClass/Reference/Reference.html

Sorry if this is completely stupid, total iOS newb here :)

Comment: Yeah .. I don't think you get any more info then those functions. Even if there is some kind of private api to get more informations using it will probably lock your app out of the app store.

Answer (score 1):

From "What's new in iOS 5.1:"

> On supported devices, iOS automatically inserts recognized phrases into the current text view when the user has chosen dictation input. The new [UIDictationPhrase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDictationPhraseClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDictationPhrase) class (declared in UITextInput.h) provides you with a string representing a phrase that a user has dictated. In the case of ambiguous dictation results, the new class provides an array containing alternative strings. New methods in the [UITextInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput) protocol allow your app to respond to the completion of dictation.

So, yeah... what you found (plus the UITextInput additions) is pretty much all there is. That's sort of the idea -- dictation is supposed to be available and transparent to use wherever there's a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the UIDictationPhrase Class Reference.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDictationPhraseClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDictationPhrase